# Querying MySQL and SQL Server from same IDE

Tags: ssms, mysql-workbench

I am currently working with MySQL and SQL Server.

For querying MySQL I use MySQL Workbench, for SQL Server I use SQL Server Management Studio.

I am mixing up shortcuts all the time. For instance, to execute a query in SSMS it's F5 and in MySQL WB it is CTRL-Enter.

Is it possible to query both databases from the same IDE? A plugin for WB or SMSS? A different IDE that works for both databases?

Comment: You could try Jetbrains 0xDBE https://www.jetbrains.com/dbe/

Comment: You could try [OmniDB](http://www.omnidb.com.br).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a lot of options but choosing the right one is up to you, this is some of the options :

1) Adminer: http://www.adminer.org/

2) DBeaver: http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/about/

3)DBVisualizer Free: http://www.dbvis.com/

4) sql developer (but you need to install the plugins first) : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html